# Django Caught an exception while rendering: No module named registration

Tags: django, django-admin, django-errors

I seem to have run into a bit of an issue.

I am busy creating an app, and over the last few weeks setup my server to use Git, mod_wsgi to host this app.

Since deploying it, everything seems to be running smoothly however, I had to go through all my files and insert the absolute url of the project to make sure it works fine.

on my local machine

from registration.models import UserRegistration

on server

from myapp.registration.models import UserRegistration

Am I doing something wrong?

And this has also caused an issue for me where I cannot access my django admin interface.

All i get is this: `Caught an exception while rendering: No module named registration`

```
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named registration
```

As far as I am concerned my app has all the relevant urls, but it does not seem to work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because somehow your local machine is adding the `myapp` directory to the PYTHONPATH, as well as its parent directory. The way to fix this is to modify your `.wsgi` script to add both these directories to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/parent')
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/parent/myapp')
```

Answer (score 1):

Read and use improved WSGI script in:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

This will set up environment to better match Django built in development server and you shoud hopefully not see a difference between the two, especially in respect of how Python module search path is handled.